# Retrieve Oracle Date/Timestamp field as is in Java java.sql.Timestamp without converting to DST

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc, dst

I have column(LOGIN_TIME) in oracle with DATE datatype. I'm trying to read it as Timestamp in Java using JDBC.
One of the rows in my table has a value of 2006-04-02 02:00:01.0 for this column. 
when I do

> select LOGIN_TIME,CAST(LOGIN_TIME as TIMESTAMP) from TABLE;

I see that sql-developer shows the value as

> 2006-04-02 02:00:01.0

But when I retrieve this column value in Java using ResultSet.getTimestamp() method, I see the value as 2006-04-02 03:00:01.0.

After a lot of googling, I understood that

1. Firstly, 2006-04-02 02:00:01.0 is invalid/lost time as after 2006-04-02 01:59:00.0 the clock clicks 2006-04-02 03:00:00.0 due to daylight saving.
2. Oracle Date/Timestamp datatypes don't maintain time zones, hence Oracle accepted this value while inserting into DB without complaint.
3. However, since 02:00:01 is an invalid time, Java by default treat it leniently and converted the time to the assumed correct time of 03:00:01.

Now, my questions are

1. Why did java assume the correct time as 03:00:01? Is it dependent on any timezone, if yes, what is the default timezone? I don't think the default timezone here is UTC because

> System.out.println(+rs.getTimestamp(index,
>   Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))));

gave me the value as

> 2006-04-01 18:00:01.0

2. How can I retrieve the value as is from Oracle without DST conversion by JDBC as 2006-04-02 02:00:01.0? or get it as 2006-04-02 03:00:01.0 and convert it back to original oracle value of 2006-04-02 02:00:01.0.

Comment: "what is the default timezone?" - `java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault().getId()` will return the current default time zone for the JVM.

Comment: Okay, that means that JDBC converts the value into JVM default timezone. Is it true that this happens only for such lost/invalid times(times lost due to day light saving) and for all other dates, jdbc gives me the actual value in database?

Comment: Yes, that's usually what happens.

Comment: Then, is there a way to get the value as is? i.e, if its stored as 2006-04-02 02:00:01.0 in oracle, is there a way to get the same value, without jdbc converting it by default?

Comment: That's what `java.time.LocalDateTime` is for. As long as you continue to use the old and deprecated `java.sql.Timestamp` you will be vexed by time zone issues.

Answer (score 2):

`Date` in Java does not store the timezone. Instead it uses your **local timezone** to represent values. That's why you see different results.

If you use Java 8 and JDBC 4.2 you may want to use a more reliable `java.time.*` package instead. It's simple as this:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = rs.getObject(index, LocalDateTime.class);
```

If you want to convert `LocalDateTime` to `java.util.Date`, you can do it this way:

```
 Instant instant = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
 Date dateFromOld = Date.from(instant);
```

Comment: sorry for some confusion. I have edited my question. I mean to say that Oracle column data type is Date and I'm trying to read it in Java as Timestamp using resultSet.getTimestamp();